# linux bash - remove all files which are in one directory from another directory

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remove all files that exist in folder `new-files` from another folder in linux using bash commands.

I need this for two things:

- I got some setup scripts which copy some pre-configured config files over. I would like to have the option to remove those files again
- Sometimes it happens that archives get unpacked into the root of your downloads directory and not into a subdir because the person packing the file put everything to the archives root

What's the best way to do that?

**Edit, to clarify:**

1. I got a folder with files called `new-files`.
2. Now I execute `cp -r new-files/* other-directory/`.
3. Lets say other-directory is not the directory I wanted to copy them to but it already contains other files so I can't just do rm other-directory/*.
4. I need to delete all folders which I accidently copied. How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the following command:

```
cd new-files ; find . -exec rm -rf path/to/other-directory/{} \;
```

It will list all the files that where copied from the `new-files` directory (`new-files` directory will not be taken in consideration). For each file, it will remove the copied version in `other-directory`.

But you've to be careful, if a file in `new-files` erase a file in `other-directory`, you won't be able to restore the old file using this method. You should consider to use a versioning system (like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) for example).

Comment: Nice one! I would recommend to use `-exec` with the trailing `+` not `;`. This is more effective as `rm` called much fewer times (similar to `xargs`).

Comment: @TrueY You can't do that. `find` throws an error if you use `+` whereas `{}` is prefixed by a non-space character.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that regex? It seems to destroy my command as it filters out `conf.d` directorys and such?

Comment: Tried to ignore hidden files. But this is not your needed. Removed it!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think it is not working as it should be. `find new-files -mindepth 1 -exec echo other-directory/{} \;` prints files like `other-directory/new-files/somefile`, isn't it? I assume `new-files\` should be removed... Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right @TrueY. We don't need the `-mindepth 1` option here. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I did not mean the `-mindepth` option. `cp -r new-files/* other-directory/` will not copy `new-files` directory under `other-directory`, but `find` tries to delete files under `other-directory/new-files`. IMHO the `new-files` should be removed from the beginning of `{}` somehow. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's true, I edit my answer to fix its problem.

Answer (score 7):

From your:

> **Edit, to clarify:**
>
> 1. I got a folder with files called `new-files`.
> 2. Now I execute `cp -r new-files/* other-directory/`.
> 3. Lets say other-directory is not the directory I wanted to copy them to but it already contains other files so I can't just do rm
>      other-directory/*.
> 4. I need to delete all folders which I accidently copied. How do I do that?

You can loop through the original dir `new-files/` and delete files with same name in the `other-directory/`:

```
for file in /new-files/*
do
   rm /other-directory/"$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

wee script to do what you want:

```
pushd `pwd`
cd /path/to/new-files
x=`find . -type f`
popd

echo $x | xargs rm
```

Comment: I mean it like this: check which files are contained in `new-files` and delete these (if they exist) from another directory

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, english isn't my native language

Comment: Do ou want it to delete files in subfolders, but not the subfolders themselves?

Comment: I think that should do it now

Comment: A shorter version could be made. It has to be run in `other-directory`: `( cd /path/to/new-files; find . -type f;)|xargs rm`.